# The Theorems of Ceva and Menelaus

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> In the parallelogram $ABCD$ $M\in AB, AM:MB=2:7$ and $N\in BC, BN:NC=4:5$. If $DM\cap AN=O$, calculate $AO:ON;DO:OM$.

[image]

For the first ratio let $BC \cap DM=Q$. By Menelaus' theorem $\dfrac{AO}{ON}\cdot\dfrac{NQ}{QB}\cdot\dfrac{BM}{MA}=1 \Rightarrow \dfrac{AO}{ON}=\dfrac{BQ}{QN}\cdot\dfrac{AM}{BM}$. If we look at the similar triangles $\triangle BMQ \sim AMD \Rightarrow \dfrac{BQ}{AD}=\dfrac{BQ}{BC}=\dfrac{BM}{AM}=\dfrac{7}{2}$ or $BQ=\dfrac{7}{2}BC$. Now, $\dfrac{AO}{ON}=\dfrac{BQ}{QN}\cdot\dfrac{AM}{BM}=\dfrac{\dfrac{7}{2}BC}{BQ+BN}\cdot\dfrac{2}{7}=\dfrac{\dfrac{7}{2}BC}{\dfrac{7}{2}BC+\dfrac{4}{9}BC}\cdot\dfrac{2}{7}=\dfrac{63}{71}\cdot\dfrac{2}{7}=\dfrac{18}{71}$. Thales theorem tells us that
$\dfrac{AO}{ON}=\dfrac{DO}{OQ}=\dfrac{18}{71}$.

How to find $DO:OM$?

Comment: Nice problem anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Let [.] denote areas. Since the triangles ADN and AMN share the same base AN,

$$\frac{DO}{OM} = \frac{[ADN]}{[AMN]} 
= \frac{\frac12[ABCD]}{\frac29[ABN]} =
= \frac{\frac12[ABCD]}{\frac29\cdot\frac4{2\cdot9}[ABCD]} = \frac{81}{8}$$

Similarly,

$$\frac{AO}{ON} = \frac{[DAM]}{[DNM]} 
= \frac{[DAM]}{[ABCD]-[DAM]-[NBM]-[DNC] } $$
$$=
= \frac{\frac2{2\cdot9}[ABCD]}
{(1-\frac2{2\cdot9}- \frac7{2\cdot9}\cdot\frac49- \frac5{2\cdot9})[ABCD]} = \frac{18}{71}$$

Comment: Thank you for the response! Very nice solution! Can we find the first ratio using a similar approach to this (using areas) or mine is fine?

Comment: @NikolDimitrova - Your 1st part is right and you could use this approach for it too, which may be simpler.

Comment: Really nice approach! I don't see why $\dfrac{DO}{OM}=\dfrac{[ADN]}{[AMN]}$. The triangles share the same base $AN$, but $DO$ and $OM$ are not altitudes.

Comment: @NikolDimitrova - since they share the base AN, the ratio is the same as that of heights via similar triangles

Comment: Which similar triangles are we talking about? $DO$ and $OM$ are not heights, right?

Comment: @NikolDimitrova - draw heights from D and M to AN

Comment: Okay! Let $DH \perp AN$ and $MH_1 \perp AN$ as $H;H_1\in AN$.

Comment: Yes, they are similar (AAA).

Comment: We can also use Thales theorem to get $\dfrac{DH}{MH_1}=\dfrac{DO}{OM}$, right?

Comment: @NikolDimitrova - I suppose, but maybe unnecessary

Comment: What is unnecessary? I think it is easier. We have $\angle AOM=\angle DON$ and the parallel lines $MH_1$ and $DH$.

Comment: @NikolDimitrova - I mean Thales is not needed since similar triangles are more familiar

Comment: Yes, but I think we have parallel lines it is easier to use Thales (Intercept theorem).

Comment: I want to use your approach for the first ratio. Can you give me a hint about the triangles that I should look at?

Comment: Hello?..........

Comment: @NikolDimitrova - added the evaluation of the 1st ratio in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $QB= t$. By Thales: $${DC\over MB}  = {QC\over QB} \implies {9\over 7}  = {t+9\over t}\implies t=63/2$$

so again by Thales:
$${AO\over ON} = {AD\over QN} = {9\over t+4} ={18\over 71}$$

---

Let $CP = x$. Again by Thales: $${x\over x+9}={CP\over DP} = {CN\over AD} = {5\over 9}\implies x=45/4$$

so

$${DO\over OM} =  {DP\over AM} = {9+x\over 2}={81\over 8 } $$

Comment: Give me some time to think through your solution. Your first result was right: $\dfrac{DO}{OM}=\dfrac{81}{8}$.

Comment: WLOG, $AB=BC=9$, right? That's what you are assuming in your solution.

Comment: yes .......................

Comment: Nikol, why do you accept an answer so quickly? You should study all the answers and then decide which one helps you most.